# Позиционирование label

Tags: html, css

Не получается задать позиционирование тексту для загрузки аватара.
Есть еще одна проблема, имеется выпадающее меню в вверху, она перестала работать из-за background а именно из-за position: relative; как это можно исправить?
В лайве у меня выглядит так http://prntscr.com/oxpa5p

```css
@import '/styles.css/normolize.css';

body {
    font-family: 'Paytone One', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.section-inner {
    max-width: 1214px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/* Каркас сайта END */

/* HEADER */
.section-menu-top {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: 15px;
    align-items: center;
}

.section-logo {
    color: #959597;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    transition: color 0.2s linear;

}

.section-logo:hover {
    color: #C4C4C4;
    opacity: 1;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Отступ сверху от меню */

.background-profile-images {
    padding-top: 26px;
}

.section-menu {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    
}

/* Цвет ссылок с плавным подсвечиванием */

.section-menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #364655;
    margin-left: 38px;
    line-height: 0.8;
    transition: color 0.2s linear;
}


/* Подсветка текста в горезонтальном меню при навидении */

.section-menu a:hover {
    color: #C4C4C4;
    opacity: 1;
}   

/* Появление выпадающего меню */

.section-menu li:hover .sub-menu  {
    display: block; 
}

/* При навидении на меню появляется фон */

.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30%;
}

/* Текст в выпадающем меню до навидения на текст */

.sub-menu a {
    color: #364655;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    display: block;
    
}

/* Меняет цвет текста в выпадающем меню */

.sub-menu a:hover {
    color: #364655;
}

/* Выделение текста в выпадающем меню при навидении */

.sub-menu a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f3f5;
    width: 60%;
}

/* Background в профиле */

.background-profile-images {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}

/* Кнопка загрузки background */

.loader-photo {
    position: absolute;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    bottom:11px;
    right:17px;
}

/* Убирает стандартную кнопку input */

.inputfile {
    overflow: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

/* Новые стили для кнопки */

.inputfile + label {
    padding: 8px 30px ;
    font-weight: 300;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer; 
}

/* Позиционирование аватра */

.avatar-profile {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 80px;
    transform: translateY(-90px);
}

/* Задается закругление к аватару в профиле */

.avatar-radius {
    border-radius: 30px;
}

/* Кнопка загрузки avatar */

.loader-avatar {
    position: absolute;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    transform: translateY(-60px);
}

/* Убираем стандартную форму загрузки, avatar */

.inputavatar {
    overflow: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.inputavatar + label {
    padding: 0 48px 16px 57px;
    font-weight: 300;
    border-radius: 13px 13px 111px 117px;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer; 
}

.asd1 {
    width: 90%;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/profile/profile.css">
        <link
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300i,700&display=swap"
            rel="stylesheet">
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="discription" content="Программы тренировок для новичков">
        <meta
            name="keywords"
            content="Программа тренировок, подтягивания, отжимания, приседания, отжимания на брусьях">
        <title>Sport-defense - profile</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <section class="section-outer section-header">
            <div class="section-inner">
                <div class="section-menu-top">
                    <a class="section-logo" href="/index.html">Sport-defense</a>
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="section-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Новости</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>

                                <a href="#">Программы тренировок</a>

                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#1">Подтягивания</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#2">Отжимания</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#3">Приседания</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#3">Брусья</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>

                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Комплексы</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Рейтинговая система</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Профиль</a>
                            </li>
                        </nav>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="background-profile-images">
                    <img src="https://cdn1.radikalno.ru/uploads/2019/8/26/1d277fb25a530c413f9dbe3bbd930195-full.jpg">

                    <form class="loader-photo">
                        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile"/>
                        <label for="file">Загрузить</label>
                    </form>

                    <div class="avatar-profile">
                        <img class="avatar-radius" src="https://cdn1.radikalno.ru/uploads/2019/8/26/b0ea8279c02e65164db14e87c64cfdc8-full.jpg">
                        
                        <form class="loader-avatar">
                                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputavatar"/>
                                <label class="asd1" for="file">Загрузить</label>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="statistic-profile">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Данные</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Статистика</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Достижения</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Фотографии</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Видео</a>
                    </li>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы выпадающее меню не скрывалось за картинкой, добавьте параметр `z-index` классу `.section-menu-top`

```
.section-menu-top {
    z-index: 100;
}
```

По поводу позиционирования текста "Загрузить", могу посоветовать следующее:

Растянуть класс`.loader-avatar` по ширине родителя

```
.loader-avatar {
width: 100%;
}
```

А также задать Ваш текст по ширине родителя, убрать все отступы (`margin` и `padding`) и выровнять текст по центру. Не забудьте удалить все остальные значения у текста. Дальше дело за малым - попробуйте поиграться со значением `padding` у текста, чтобы найти идеальное для Вас решение.

```
.asd1 {
width: 100%;
margin: 0!important;
padding: 0!important;
text-align: center;
```

}

Так выглядит Ваш сайт в Google Chrome

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, с меню получилось, что на счет label, у меня такая проблема выходит, если просмотреть код на сайте (тут) где загружать аватар есть кнопка, в просмотре она выглядит более менее нормально, а вот у меня в лайве (то есть через vc code есть дополнение которое дает возможность запускать сайт в браузере) отображается эта кнопка загрузки по другому http://prntscr.com/oy36o5 а должно она выглядеть вот так как в макете, не могу понять как сделать http://prntscr.com/oy370b получается больше пространства между словом

Comment: Обновил ответ по поводу позиционирования текста

Comment: Нет почему то не работает